# Calculating confidence intervall for quantiles first by hand (than in R)

Tags: r, percentile, confidence-interval, quantile

It would be great if someone can check whether my approach is correct or not. 
Question in short will be, if the error calculation is the correct way.
lets assume i have the following data.

```
data = c(23.7,25.47,25.16,23.08,24.86,27.89,25.9,25.08,25.08,24.16,20.89)
```

Furthermore i want to check if my data follows a normal distribution.

**Edit**:  I know that there are tests etc. but i will concentrate on constructing the qqplot with confidence lines. I know that there is a method in the car package, but i want to understand the building of these lines.

So i calculate the percentiles for my sample data as well as for my theoretical distribution (with estimated `mu = 24.6609`and `sigma = 1.6828`. So i end up with these two vectors containing the percentiles.

```
percentileReal =  c(23.08,23.7,24.16,24.86,25.08,25.08,25.16,25.47,25.90)
percentileTheo =  c(22.50,23.24,23.78,24.23,24.66,25.09,25.54,26.08,26.82)
```

Now i want to calculate the confidence intervall for `alpha=0.05` for the theoretical percentiles. If i rembember myself correct, the formula is given by

```
error = z*sigma/sqrt(n),
value = +- error
```

with `n=length(data)` and `z=quantil of the normal distribution for the given p`.

So in order to get the confidence intervall for the 2nd percentile i'll do the following:

```
error = (qnorm(20+alpha/2,mu,sigma)-qnorm(20-alpha/2,mu,sigma))*sigma/sqrt(n)
```

Insert the values:

```
error = (qnorm(0.225,24.6609,1.6828)-qnorm(0.175,24.6609,1.6828)) * 1.6828/sqrt(11)
error = 0.152985
confidenceInterval(for 2nd percentil) = [23.24+0.152985,23.24-0.152985]
confidenceInterval(for 2nd percentil) = [23.0870,23.3929]
```

Finally i have

```
percentileTheoLower = c(...,23.0870,.....)
percentileTheoUpper = c(...,23.3929,.....)
```

same for the rest....

So what do you think, can i go with it?

Comment: I recommend you read this article: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf It contains some information about normality tests

Comment: @Barranka Thanks for your answer. I read this article, but i dont want to know how to test on normal distribution. I simply want to calculate the confidenceinterval for each percentile. The normal distribution was only meant as example.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Is there a simple way to transfer this post to stats? okay i just copied the text ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to test if the data follows a normal distribution, use the [shapiro.wilk test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/shapiro.test.html):

```
shapiro.test(data)
# Shapiro-Wilk normality test
# data:  data
# W = 0.9409, p-value = 0.5306
```

`1-p` is the probability that the distribution is *non-normal*. So, since `p>0.05` we cannot assert that the distribution is non-normal. A crude interpretation is that "there is a 53% chance that the distribution is normal."

You can also use `qqplot(...)`. The more nearly linear this plot is, the more likely it is that your data is normally distributed.

```
 qqnorm(data)
```

[image]

Finally, there is the [nortest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nortest/nortest.pdf) package in R which has, among other things, the Pearson Chi-Sq test for normality:

```
 library(nortest)
 pearson.test(data)
 #  Pearson chi-square normality test
 #  data:  data
 #  P = 3.7273, p-value = 0.2925
```

This (more conservative) test suggest that there is only a 29% chance that the distribution is normal. All these tests are fully explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew about the testing, but my goal was to get the confidence interval for each percentile in order to plot the range in the qq plot. I know that there is already a method like this (e.g. in the car package), but i want to understand the calculation of these lines.